# How can I use arbitrary length integers in Perl?

Tags: perl, integer, arbitrary-precision

Is there any standard way to use integers of arbitrary length in Perl?  I am working on code that generates x64 assembly for tests, and I'm tired of manipulating 32 bits at a time.

I'm using Perl 5.10.0, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you only want to use big integers, you can use the `bigint`, which you can scope to a file:

```
 use bigint;
```

or just a limited scope:

```
 {
 use bigint;
 ...;
 }
```

If you need big floating point numbers as well as big integers, you can use the `bignum` pragma in the same way. Either way, these will slow down your program slightly (or significantly if you are doing a lot of math), so you should only use them for the parts where you really need them. However, faster isn't better than correct. :)

If you want very precise control over which numbers use the `big*` math, you can use the underlying classes that implement them and create objects yourself rather than applying the `big*` semantics to everything. Look that `Math::Big*` modules.

I talk about this more in the Benchmarking chapter of [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242) since computers are too fast nowadays to use a factorial as a slow function, and we also added a section on big numbers it to the upcoming [Effective Perl Programming, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321496949).

Answer (score 15):

[`use Math::BigInt`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::BigInt)

Comment: and possibly `use bigint;` which makes *every* numeric literal in its scope a BigInt without `Math::BigInt->new`. Use with care, of course.

Comment: Or `use bignum;`, which extends bigint with BigFloat.