# Large number base conversion

Tags: shell

Is there any shell command to convert large numbers from one base to another

for ex:

> ```
>   Converting 1024-bit binary number into hexadecimal number
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at `bc`, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_%28programming_language%29). E.g. convert 12 to binary (output base = 2)

```
echo 'obase=2;12' | bc
1100
```

And also `dc`, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_%28computer_program%29).

And also `printf`. E.g.

```
printf "%x" 32
20
```

Or you can Perl with `bigint` or `bignum`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126420/how-can-i-use-arbitrary-length-integers-in-perl). E.g.

```
perl -e '$line="1101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111110111101010110110111110111011111101111010101101101111101110111111011110101011011011111011101111";$hex=unpack("H*",pack("B*",$line));print $hex'
```

Output:

```
deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef
```

Also, you can use `xxd` to convert hex to binary:

```
echo -n $'\x02\x02' | xxd -b
0000000: 00000010 00000010
```

Comment: all the options you have given only works for smaller numbers it doesn't work for 1024-bit numbers